# How to edit default search in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, search, home-page

I want to edit default search bar in Magento 2. What I would like to have is to display the search icon and when the customer clicks the icon I want to show the search bar.

To do that, where to update the code?

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: Can you please post demo image or something else?

Comment: Edit this file: vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/result.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some thing like this one.

1. Create one custom extension and overide magento 2 default search file into extension. for that one create the `default.xml` file at following location.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <referenceBlock name="top.search">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Extension::form.mini.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

2. now copy `form.mini.phtml` phtml from

> vendor\magento\module-search\view\frontend\templates\form.mini.phtml

To

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\templates\form.mini.phtml

Now you can change, what every you want to do here.